# Open-source inventory agent

Tags: linux

Can anyone recommend a good open-source inventory-agent, which would help enumerate both software and hardware on Linux servers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have a look at [OCS Inventory](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/index.php?page=Supported_OS). I don't use the agent on linux/*nix platforms but if it behaves like in windows that's a great solution.

EDIT: It is possible to use it in conjunction with [GLPI](http://www.glpi-project.org/spip.php?lang=en) as they can share inventory datas, this setup provides a incident tracking system based on the inventory provided by OCS.

Comment: I use OCS Inventory as a stand-alone for hardware inventorying on Linux platforms.