# Open Source Inventory System

Tags: open-source

I have about 200 Hosts I need to inventory. Several of them are not able to be inventoried by OCS inventory, because they are firewalls and switches, or shutoff. I also have had issues with adding hosts that are moved to new machines causing duplicate entries in OCS inventory. I also would like an LDAP authentication solution.

I'm aware of GLPI, but that's just moves the issues I have with OCS inventory to another system.

I would very much love to have something where I can manage IP networks, DNS and rack location.

Is there an option that is not OCS inventory?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning which OS you need to do this for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open-source inventory agent](http://serverfault.com/q/99683/2321)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is such an open-source tool but there is a [rack plugin](http://www.glpi-project.org/wiki/doku.php?id=en:plugins:rack_use) for GLPI which has a lot of nice features to manage racks.

OTOH, I've recently discovered [GestioIP](http://www.gestioip.net/) which seems to be a great (and automated) open-source tool to manage ip addresses and VLANs. GestioIP can automatically update the networks against OCS inventory, providing easy integration, among other nice features.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want OCSinventory?

Then try [FusionInventory](http://fusioninventory.org)